# Why do we use for loop outside addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

The code is as below:

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(var i=0; i< lis.length ; i++){
   lis[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
      this.style.color = "pink";
   }); 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>There</li>
  <li>How are you today?</li>
</ul>
```

I know this code want particular clicked li item to be changed.
In my conception that I got, the for loop has the order from 0 to 2.

but if I clicked the third `li` item (it means `<li>How are you today?</li>`) the third one color will be changed to pink,
then after that I clicked the first `li` item (it means `<li>Hi</li>`) the color will be changed too.

So I don't know why `for` loop is placed outside `addEventListener`?

and before I trigger the event "click",the `for` loop `i` has already be count to `3`.

Does it not mean the `for` loop condtion is false?

Additionally, I click `li` item  that is not from first one, the clicked order is random, why `for` loop still works?

I will appreciate any response from anyone of you.

Thanks

Comment: The loop is only used to attach an event listener to every element in the list. Nothing more. Think of it in terms of "for each element in the list, attach an event handler to it".  At the time one of the event handlers is executed the loop has already terminated and is of no significance.

Comment: It's not clear what are your expectations from the code above. The code seems to work as expected.

Comment: I think you haven't understood the concept of event listeners. Yes the for loop ran and it exited. Your code is not stuck inside the loop. But in the loop you have attached a few listeners to the li's. So as long as they are in the webpage and you didn't "unlisten", everytime you click on the li, it responds by calling the function attached to it. The anonymous func inside the addEventListener is a reference that will be called in future . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop enumerates every `li` tags in your document.
The `addEventListener` call is placed inside the `for` loop to bind a function - that colors the text in pink - when the current enumerated elemnt is clicked.

In other words, when you click on an element, it triggers the anonymous function you have passed in the addEventListener call, not the whole script :

```
function(){
   this.style.color = "pink";
}
```

The `for` loop is executed only once, when the script tag is loaded in your document.

Answer (score 0):

What the for loop does is adding click listeners to each of your `li`s. When the user is clicking on one of the elements, the function (`handleClick` below) is triggered. I refactored the code, so it's possibly easier to read it. <strike>`.bind(li[i])` adds the correct context to the function, so `this` works in `handleClicks`.</strike>

```js
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(var i=0; i < lis.length; i++){
  // lis[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick.bind(li[i]));
  lis[i].addEventListener("click", handleClick);
}

function handleClick() {
  this.style.color = "pink";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Hi</li>
    <li>There</li>
    <li>How are you today?</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: The correct `this` is passed anyway, because the handler is called from the event queue, you don't need manually bind the `this` value in this case. (In practice, `bind` just wraps the code in a newly-created function, and by using the reference doesn't save memory compared to the OP's code. Without `bind` it makes a small reduce to the memory consumption.)